# How to include laravel ..env variable into js file

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

i am trying to include laravel .env variable into my js file my file name is custom-script.js and my js code is:

```
     function sendBusinessDetails(postForm) {

    $.ajax({//Process the form using $.ajax()
        type: 'post', //Method type
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/Process', //Your form processing file URL
        data: postForm, //Forms name
        dataType: 'json',
```

and my .env file contain

```
 APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

how i can replace APP_URL=http://localhost:8000 into my  url: 'http://localhost:8000/Process',

Your help will be highly appreciated

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post', //Method type
            url: '{{env("API_URL")}}/api/apikey?api_key
```

Comment: `url : '{{env("APP_URL")}}/'+'Process';` Doesn't this work for you ?

Comment: its not working here

Comment: please see my question i have shared

Comment: `url: '{{env("API_URL")}}'+'/process'+'/api/apikey?api_key'` You need to concatenate process

Comment: forget about the old url

Comment: here  $.ajax({
                type: 'post', //Method type
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/apikey?api_key

Comment: and .env value is   API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 5):

In your `blade` file:

```
<script>
    var action = "{{ env("APP_URL") }}"
</script>
```

In your `js`:

```
url : action+'/process',
```

Comment: please see my eidt question

Comment: Actually, what are you want to do?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'post', //Method type
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/apikey?api_key='+ connectApi +'&token

Comment: i want to replace http://127.0.0.1:8000 with API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: this is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another alternative.

Delete your **custom-script.js** file from your public directory

In your **Route** (web.php)

```
Route::get('/custom-script.js','ScriptController@index');
```

In your **ScriptController**

```
class ScriptController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return response()->view('custom-script')->header('Content-Type','application/javascript');
    }

}
```

Now put your js code in **custom-script.blade.php** file

```
alert('{{ env("APP_URL") }}');
```